# Parse.com: [task.results filteredArrayUsingPredicate] throws objec_exception_thrown with Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nspredicate, xcode7

The following code worked fine on iOS 8 with Xcode 6 but throws objec_exception_thrown in debug when compiled with Xcode 7 on iOS 8 and and iOS 9. I am using Parse version 1.9.0 for iOS.

```
 [[localQuery findObjectsInBackground] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {

    NSArray *results = task.result;
    Level *level = [[LevelManager sharedManager] currentLevel];
    int numberOfSolvedLevels = (int) [results count];
    int levelNumber = (int)level.serialNumber;
    int firstLevelInSection = ((levelNumber / LEVELSECTION_SIZE)*10);
    int lastLevelInSection = firstLevelInSection + LEVELSECTION_SIZE;

    // Get all the levels in the same range from the local query result
    NSPredicate *betweenPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"estimatedData.level_num BETWEEN {%d,%d}", firstLevelInSection, lastLevelInSection];
    // Throws objec_exception_thrown
    NSArray *playedLevelsInBetweenRangeArray = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:betweenPredicate];
    ....
    return task;
}];
```

The exception is thrown here:

```
 NSArray *playedLevelsInBetweenRangeArray = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:betweenPredicate];
```

The exception is thrown in a parse thread (Queue: com.parse-sqlitedb.queue (serial)).

Any info how to fix this? And it looks the exception in only thrown when running in debug mode.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Thread 16Queue : com.parse.sqlite.db.queue (serial)
#0  0x000000019a277f48 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x0000000185878c1c in -[NSException raise] ()
#2  0x000000018677dd90 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] ()
#3  0x00000001866d00cc in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] ()
#4  0x00000001866cff68 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] ()
#5  0x0000000186712cec in -[NSFunctionExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:] ()
#6  0x00000001867127d0 in -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] ()
#7  0x0000000186711728 in _filterObjectsUsingPredicate ()
#8  0x0000000186711524 in -[NSArray(NSPredicateSupport) filteredArrayUsingPredicate:] ()
```

This is my only real debug info:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PFObjectEstimatedData 0x135b57f60> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key level_num.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown because of your `betweenPredicate` is invalid. You should not try to access `estimatedData`, this is a `PFObject` private ivar.

If the objects you get in the `results` array have a `level_num` property, your predicate should simply be :

```
NSPredicate *betweenPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"level_num BETWEEN {%d,%d}", firstLevelInSection, lastLevelInSection];
```

Comment: Thank you, this works with Xcode 7. Still don't know why it did work with Xcode 6.x...